# "Cycle" through specific ASCII code-range

Tags: java, char, ascii

I am supposed to create a program in Java which takes an upper case letter from the User, subtracts 2 from the ASCII code and outputs the resulting letter. The clue is that I am only supposed to output letters from A-Z meaning after Z it starts again at A.
What is the best way to do this? The obvious way to remove 26 if a value is reached seems inappropriate.

Hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using what programming language?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Java!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chars in Java can be treated as numbers and you can perform ordinary arithmetic on them. The byte value for 'A' is equivalent to 65 (i.e. in an ASCII table, capital A is the 65th ASCII table, capital B is 66, etc.). I wrote some simple code with the steps required broken down:

```
letter = (letter - 65);
letter = (letter - 2);
if (letter < 0) letter = letter + 26;
letter = letter + 65;
```

The first line subtracts the position of 'A' in the ASCII table. This means 'A' becomes  0, 'B' becomes 1, etc. The next line subtracts two and the following line ensures it "loops back" to the end of the alphabet if
subtraction caused it to become negative. The final line adds 65 back to the letter, returning it to capital letter in the ASCII table.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it out and first off all is it correct that I need to add a cast to every line? Since I can't use Strings there. Moreover, it does not work like intended. It doesn't cycle through the alphabet, it just goes 2 backwards, resulting in "?" if you enter an "A". Any idea why? After reading your code I was sure it would work like this :O Okay, well, it outputs always a "?"... Im confused... I figured out that it works like intended if you change letter < 0 to letter > 0 but I don't understand why :O